# ReactJS Tic Tac Toe - Different Way to write OnClick Event with This

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tic-tac-toe

Ref to ReactJS tutorial.
https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#setup-option-2-local-development-environment

```
<button className="square" onClick={()=>alert('u clicked' + this)}>
```

The code above is working fine.
However, when i had made the changes.

```
button className="square" onClick={function() {alert('u clicked: ' + this)}}>
```

the code above is not working.

Based on the explanation from (https://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/), **THIS** will be auto binded. How can we manual bind for second code?

---

Next modification i had made

```
<button className="square" onClick={alert('u clicked' + this)}>
```

**THIS** is shown, but it was called, during load. Why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example, `<button className="square" onClick={()=>alert('u clicked' + this)}>`, the `onClick` prop is assigned an arrow function, in which `this` refers to the context in which the button is created.

To bind `this` in the same way for the second example, follow the function definition with `.bind(this)`:

```
<button className="square" onClick={function() {alert('u clicked: ' + this)}.bind(this)}>
```

Your last modification assigns `alert('u clicked' + this)`'s return value to the `onClick` property.